# My Laravel project fails with a "whoops" error

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

I am getting this error:

> ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 111:
>   file_put_contents(D:\HR\storage\framework/sessions/813a57c5cfa882188bd437312dd11400e7d5e446):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: share some code so we can help.

Comment: code is working perfect in other pc too but iam getting error in my pc .i just installed laravel in my pc and checking it

Comment: try with `php artisan cache:clear` and than again start laravel server with `php artisan serve`. If that will not work for you then again download dependancy of laravel.

Comment: ok fine i will try it out

Comment: Did you check to see if that file and path exists?

Comment: actually their is no D directory . but it is taking D directory .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flush composer's autoload cache. I guess this project taken from another computer. Try this;

```
php artisan view:clear
composer dump-autoload
composer update
```